# OverflowError when trying to encrypt

Tags: python, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt bytes with the [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) library like this:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = b'12gegh7yiJ2NK39yBLXtvjxojhfeefTCXlHJNCz9eU3='
Fernet(key).encrypt(my_bytes)
```

where

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(classifier_bytes)
```

is `3539843486` , but I get a

> OverflowError: integer 3539843456 does not fit '32-bit int'

I guess `my_bytes` is too large? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Split your bytes into two parts and encrypt part 1 and part 2 separately.  Reassemble after decryption.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Fernet in pyca/cryptography cannot currently handle >2GiB files. An issue to fix this has been opened: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/5418

You can invoke fernet yourself multiple times, but be aware that unless you add additional metadata to the encrypted payload you may make yourself vulnerable to chunk reordering and truncation attacks.

Update: This issue has been resolved in pyca/cryptography 3.1.